# How can i count the total numbers of an ip from a logfile?

Tags: c#

For example with the argument:

/search ip 123.12.12.167

123.12.12.167 - 120 (120 is the total amount of the ip from the logfile)

Comment: read the log file with streamwrtier and put all the data into array and count it using your input IP.

Comment: `string result = $"{ip} - {File.ReadLines(logPath).Count(l => l.Contains(ip))}";`

Answer (score 0):

- Make a variable (int) and set it to 0.
- loop through every like and check if the IP is the IP you put in the search query, if so increment the variable by 1
- Output the variable data to the console (or do something else with it)

Comment: Can you back that up with a code sample?

Comment: I unfortunately don't code in c#, sorry